# Enumeration (enum in lua) .Want to use enum in lua5.2.4

Tags: enums, lua, freeswitch

I have a condition where in my lua script I want to use enum like for SUCCESS I can give 1 and for FAILURE I can give 0
I am using lua version 5.2.4
Can anyone please help me on how to use enum
I want to use enum

```
elseif(cc_config_cmd == "DELETE" and file_found==1)then
            api:executeString("callcenter_config queue unload " .. queue_name)
            stream:write("1")
else
            stream:write("0")

end
```

Answer (score 24):

There are no enums in Lua.

Simply define variables.

```
SUCCESS = "1"
FAILURE = "0"

stream:write(SUCCESS)
```

Or put it into a table which would be quite similar to enum style syntax.

```
Result = {SUCCESS = "1", FAILURE = "0"}
stream:write(Result.SUCCESS)
```

Comment: Upvoting this for the "put your enum values in a table" recommendation!

Answer (score 5):

Lua does not have native support for "enums", but they are quite easy to emulate.

Naively, they can be implemented as a table that contains unique values for each key. While strings or numbers suffice, I find that simply using empty tables work best:

```lua
local Result = { 
   Success = {},
   Failure = {},
}
```

Since Lua's comparison operator (`==`) for table check if the two sides are *the same object*, not if they have the same fields, `Result.Sucess ~= Result.Failure`. This is more efficient than comparing two strings and saves the developer from the hassle of picking a unique value for each field.

In a unityped languages such as Lua, a record of unique values acts pretty much as an enum in other languages.

If the syntax is too alien for you, this mechanism can be easily automated:

```lua
local enum = function(keys)
    local Enum = {}
    for _, value in ipairs(keys) do
        Enum[value] = {} 
    end
    return Enum
end

local Result = enum { "Success", "Failure" }
assert(Result.Success == Result.Success)
assert(Result.Failure == Result.Failure)
assert(Result.Success ~= Result.Failure)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no `enums` in `Lua`, you can use strings such as your current code. The strings will be interned inside the `Lua Virtual Machine`, so in the memory the strings will not be duplicated.

Another option will be to use numbers in place of strings.

```
local COMMAND_DELETE = 1
local COMMAND_TEST_1 = 2
local COMMAND_TEST_2 = 3
```

Other options would be to use a third-party package such as the [`enum`](https://www.lexaloffle.com/bbs/?tid=29891) package or maybe go further and use a [`Lua Preprocessor`](https://github.com/ReFreezed/LuaPreprocess)